# Firestore Rules with an Or operator - Billing Question -

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this update rule

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.abc == resource.data.abc || exists(path/to/document)
```

If the first condition is true; the rule after or is it also executed?

Comment: as long as either one is `True`, the condition is run.

Comment: no order? I think it is relevant for billing

Comment: yes it does check all statuses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules engine currently short-circuits the evaluation. So if the first condition of an `||` is `true` then the second condition isn't evaluated.

Note that this is not documented, so it may change at some point. For example, if parallel evaluation of the conditions would speed up the evaluation time for the entire rule.